# Change windows form controls values by Quatz scheduled job in C sharp

Tags: c#, quartz

I have Quartz job scheduler runs on periodically and want to update a label in windows form application. below is my job execute method and Test method has label text change code. i tried using delegates and it gives me an error:

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window
> handle has been created

How do i update a form control value from a job scheduler time to time.

```
public class Scheduler : IJob
    {
        private readonly Form1 obj;
        public Scheduler()
        {
            obj = new Form1();
        }
     
        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
             obj.Test();
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you should show your form first, I am not sure